# Make Pandoc recognize 'ragged right' attribute

Tags: latex, pandoc, tex, pypandoc

I'm converting plenty of documents from Word, LibreOffice and HTML into TeX source. I've encountered this issue that Pandoc is unable to recognize the text being ragged right and thus the text stays on the left although it was supposed to be on the right.

I have tried many file types to see if some doesn't get parsed better, but it's all the same.

If there is any good way of making pandoc automatically recognize the ragged right attribute in ODT, DOCX or any other format, I'd highly appreciate pointing me towards the reight direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whether text is ragged left, justified, or ragged right is considered a formatting detail. As the pandoc manual states:

> Pandoc attempts to preserve the structural elements of a document, but
> not formatting details [...]

You might be able to carry some of the information over by trying different settings and using [filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters). The best approach is to look at the "native" output and check what kind of information is retained in pandoc's internal format. It's not possible to say more without seeing the documents that you are trying to convert.